# How can a class identify its own objects in C#

Tags: c#, oop

I have a class. In c#, is there some way (which i can implement in a static method) which can identify an object of this class, instantiated by some other (calling) class?

**Scenario**
Actually I have a class of Country, which contains a member Rectangle (having 4 coordinates). I want to write a static method which, when passed a point or vector2d, searches for that point in each of the instantiated objects of Country and can return ref of that object.
I have Rectangle.Contains(point) method which tells if that point lies in calling rectangle.

Comment: Sounds like you a searching for a diversion of the Flyweight pattern. You might want to look into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to store all instances of your class in a collection, and search the collection to find the specific object you need.

You *could* make this collection a static member of your class, but it doesn't need to be. It could instead be stored elsewhere as an ordinary member of another class. For example if you have a `CountryFactory` that you use to construct your `Country` objects then each time the factory constructs a country it could also store a reference to that country in a collection inside the factory.

Remember also to remove the country from the collection when you no longer need it, otherwise it won't be garbage collected (or use a [`WeakReference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.aspx)).

Comment: this is what i am doing. I have an array in my Game class, and I loop through all elements and check if a point is contained in it. But isnt there a better way? Why does not a class get to know all of the instantiated objects (somewhere else) of its own type?

Comment: if something kept a list of all constructed objects then those objects would never be eligible to garbage collection as something would always have a reference to them.  If you want that functionality then you have to implement it.

Comment: got it now. do i have to close this question (how?) or just leave it as it is

Comment: @bilal.haider: `and I loop through all elements and check if a point is contained in it. But isnt there a better way?` You could use LINQ queries on your collection to avoid having to manually loop through it. You may also want to consider storing your objects in a way that is more efficient for searching. You could look at an [R-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) for example. That allows very efficient searches for rectangles that contain a specific point.

Comment: isnt it inefficient? i mean these full length loops and then inside an if-check and for that a function call? sorry i am building my first project

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to have the points have a reference to their parent Rectangle and then Rectangle have a reference to their parent Country.  Then the static function would simply be:

```
public Country FindCountry(Point p)
{
    return p.Rectangle.Country;
}
```

Of course there could be checks for nulls and such, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Why does it have to be a static method?

To solve the problem you need a collection of all countries that you can loop through and check each one against a point.  How you keep that collection is up to you.  You could store it in some object.  It could be a static list inside the Country class, and as new Countries are created using the constructor they are added to the list, or the list could just be a fixed static list, or it could be in some factory which creates Country objects and store a reference to them as they are created.  It probably depends on what fits best with how your countries are created at the moment.  One thing to watch out for with keeping a list of objects that are created is that you need to remove them from the list when they are no longer needed so that they can be garbage collected, otherwise the memory from them will never be freed.

You could have a method on Country which you pass a point and it returns whether its rectangle contains that point, or you could expose the rectangle from the country and as it from outside.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a built-in way to get all objects of a class.
Just using a static dictionary (or another collection type) filled with all objects is the best way I know. Like so:

```
private static Dictionary<string /*name*/, Country> _countryDict =
  new List<Country>
    {
      new Country("Country1", new Rectangle(100, 200, 100, 100)),
      new Country("Country2", new Rectangle(200, 200, 100, 100))
    }.ToDictionary(c => c.Name);
```

But I guess you have already thought in this direction.